# Encountering an error while logging out of Google Authenticated PHP application

Tags: php, google-authentication

I am using Google authentication for login into an PHP application which works fine but facing an issue while logging out of the application. I am using Gmail's login page as a first page to get log in to my PHP application, on logging out of the application it does not get redirected to the login page.
Here is the implemented code for same:

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {

session_unset();

  $client->revokeToken();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

}
```

Comment: is `$redirect_uri` has valid url address?

Comment: Yes, it has valid url address